# apache, httaccess: write a rule so that xxxxx.txt means "return the source code of xxxxx.php"

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, rewrite

I'm not sure this is possible, but I'd like to write a rewrite rule (and any other instruction if needed) in a .htaccess file so that, for every url in that folder, any url ending in .txt is rewritten to the same name ending in .php, but in addition, in this case the php file is NOT executed but its content (source code) is served instead.

That is, being "myfolder" the folder where I want this to apply:

http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/somescript.php
 => would run somescript.php as usual
http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/somescript.txt 
 => would return the source code of somescript.php without running it

Comment: Well I've solved this by writing a little php script and then rewriting xxxx.txt into getsource.php?file=xxxx.php

Anyway I'm still curious about a solution that would not involve writing a php script to get the source.

In my workaround, the rewrite rule is: RewriteRule (.*)\.txt$ getsource.php?file=$1.php

and the php script getsource.php is like this:

<?php
$content=file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
echo $content;
?>

Comment: Look into highlight_file() (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) -  your script is insecure, you need to perform sanity checking on the directory, someone could pass '../../db.php' to that script and get it output.

Comment: When hitting a PHP file post-rewrite, it should always be passed to the PHP handler - this is a **very good thing** for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of accomplishing this.

1. Symlink each `.php` file to `.txt` and add a directive in Apache like:

   ```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .txt
   ```

   within a `<VirtualHost>`, `<Location>` or `<Directory>` block.

   Putting it inside a `<Location`> is probably best so that .txt files aren't globally associated as being PHP source.
2. Use a rewrite rule such as:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(/myfolder/.+)\.txt $1.php [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
   ```

   (source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_h - modified slightly)

   With this option, ensure that no other files will exist in the directory called `.txt` otherwise they will be sent with a Content-type of x-httpd-php-source. You may need to adjust the regex if this is the case.

Comment: Do you mean to use that in conjunction with a rewrite rule such as RewriteRule (.*).txt$ $.php ? Or will the AddTyle alone accomplish what I described??

Comment: The `AddType` alone should do it. You don't need any rewrite. application/x-httpd-php-source is part of mod_php.

Comment: No it doesn't. What it does is that existing txt files are served with the Content-Type header "application/x-httpd-php-source". What I asked was that by requesting somefile.txt you would obtain the source of somefile.php as plain text

Comment: Ah. You didn't say you have existing .txt files you want to serve, just that foo.txt should return the source of foo.php. I don't think there is a way to do what you want. Usually people use .phps to get the PHP source.

Comment: Even if I DON'T have txt files that I want to serve, your AddType declaration does not cause foo.txt to return the source of foo.php

Comment: Did you symlink foo.php to foo.txt? Of course it won't work if foo.txt doesn't contain the source code.

Comment: Of course it won't, that's why it doesn't even remotely answer my question. Symlinking is not an option, as I would have to do it manually file by file.

Comment: but I do appreciate the information contained in your answer, as I didn't know the application/x-httpd-php-source mime type, which regardless of answering my question or not is useful

Comment: I'd say that the symlinking is perhaps the better option as it gives you better control and can be scripted to add/delete symlinks. However I've modified my answer to include a rewrite rule that should work.